# Ubuntu document

Tags: xubuntu

I want to be Linux administrator and I have not to much document and I was set up on ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop and always learning ubuntu but I need an Ubuntu document please give me ubuntu document book or link. THANKS!

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is EOL since 19th July 2018, 18.04 is the current version.

Comment: There are lots of documentation sources - the first from Bruni is the wiki (help.ubuntu.com), another is the Ubuntu Manual project (https://ubuntu-manual.org/) which is more user-oriented.  Ubuntu 17.10 is a standard release with a supported life of only 9 months, which ended 2018-July-19 (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases which is from wiki). Ubuntu releases are in yy.mm in format, so 17.10 means 2017-October release (+9 = 2018-July).  Long Term Support (or LTS) releases have a 5 year support - so you should install 18.04 LTS; or try `do-release-upgrade` to see the upgrade process quickly.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "Howto install ubuntu" on google or another search engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indeed what you are searching is the official Ubuntu documentation, this should be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/